# Unable to call php function and unable to show results

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

There are three files
1). classes/header_featured.php

```
<?php
    class header_featured{
        function getfeatured() {
            global $db;
            $ads = array();
            $featured_ads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class_ads where active=1 and featured=1 limit 50"); 
            while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($featured_ads)) { 
                $record = array();
                $record['ad_id']      = $temp['id'];
                $record['ad_title']   = $temp['title'];

                //check for image if featured ad have image (Need to fetch only single image)
                $featured_ads_images = mysql_query("select * from class_ads_pictures where ad_id={$record['ad_id']} order by order_no"); 
                $img = mysql_fetch_assoc($featured_ads_images);
                $record['img_id']         = $img['id'];
                $record['ad_img']         = $img['picture'];
               $record['img_folder']     = $img['folder'];

                $ads[] = $record;
            } 
        }
    }
?>
```

2). h_featured.php

```
<?php

require_once "include/include.php";
require_once "classes/header_featured.php";
global $db;
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty = common($smarty);

$obj = new header_featured();
$featured_ads = $obj->getfeatured();
$smarty->assign('featured_ads ', $featured_ads );

$db->close();
if($db->error!='') { $db_error = $db->getError(); $smarty->assign('db_error',$db_error); }

$smarty->display('h_featured.html');
close();
?>
```

3). templates/h_featured.html

```
 {foreach item=item  from=$no_featured} 
  {$item.ad_id}
  {$item.ad_title}
  {$item.img_id}
  {$item.ad_img}
  {$item.img_folder}
 {/foreach}
```

What i want basically, I want to show featured ads in my website header so for this i created a file "classes/header_featured.php" in which i am fetchings rows from database and then i created another file in root "h_featured.php" in which i am calling the function of feature ads and assign variables to smarty file "templates/h_featured.html" but it not working for me it look like no display or no calling of function or no assign of data ...

Please help ..

Comment: 1) Poor design. 2) Don't use `mysql_*` functions. 3) You aren't returning anything in your getfeatured() function (please camelCase)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out .. but can you give me solution for my problem ...?

Comment: You would do better to learn about proper naming conventions, user-defined functions, prepared SQL statements, etc. In this case, I will not simply hand you an answer

Answer (score 3):

Your method `getfeatured` does not return anything. So `$featured_ads` will be empty.

Comment: So what have to do ... can you please complete the code ...

Answer (score 0):

In your files classes/header_featured.php should be:

```
<?php
    class header_featured{
        function getfeatured() {
            global $db;
            $ads = array();
            $featured_ads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class_ads where active=1 and featured=1 limit 50"); 
            while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($featured_ads)) { 
                $record = array();
                $record['ad_id']      = $temp['id'];
                $record['ad_title']   = $temp['title'];

                //check for image if featured ad have image (Need to fetch only single image)
                $featured_ads_images = mysql_query("select * from class_ads_pictures where ad_id={$record['ad_id']} order by order_no"); 
                $img = mysql_fetch_assoc($featured_ads_images);
                $record['img_id']         = $img['id'];
                $record['ad_img']         = $img['picture'];
               $record['img_folder']     = $img['folder'];

                $ads[] = $record;
            }
            return $ads;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: No success ... Do you have believe other code is fine ...

Comment: Thanks ... its working with $obj = new header_featured();
$ads = $obj->getfeatured();
$smarty->assign('ads', $ads);